# Centering Tesselator Shape in Kivy

Tags: python, layout, kivy, kivy-language

Well I am using an 'experimental' feature in kivy called Tesselator (https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.tesselator.html). Currently my app draws a wee shape in the bottom left. It doesn't use a .kv file.

I would like to know the best way to make the shape remain centred on the screen as you change the window's size? I have seen how to do this with the basic shapes, but I can't figure out how to do this with a tessellated shape.

Any suggestions and advice is much appreciated! The code is below.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Mesh
from kivy.graphics.tesselator import Tesselator
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class MapBackground(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MapBackground, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.shapes = [
            [100, 100, 300, 100, 300, 300, 100, 300],
            [150, 150, 250, 150, 250, 250, 150, 250]
        ]        
        self.draw()

    # draws the map shape
    def draw(self):
        # make the tesselator object
        tess = Tesselator()
        # add all the shapes
        for shape in self.shapes:
            if len(shape) >= 3:
                tess.add_contour(shape)
        # call the tesselate method to compute the points 
        if not tess.tesselate(): # returns false if doesn't work
            print('tesselator did\'t work:(')
            return
        # clear canvas
        self.canvas.clear()
        # draw shapes
        for vertices, indices in tess.meshes:
            self.canvas.add(Mesh(
                vertices=vertices,
                indices=indices,
                mode='triangle_fan'
            ))

class TimmApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'The Interactive Museum Map'
        return MapBackground()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TimmApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did what I wanted by making the widget the shape was drawn in to be inside a float layout. Then (using the kv file seen below) I binded a method called draw() to the event on_size. This meant that the shape was redrawn whenever the window changed shape. I won't show the code for draw() because it's a lot.

```
#:kivy 1.11.1

FloatLayout:
    MapBackground:
        on_size: self.draw()
```